# Traffic manager endpoint Degraded

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, endpoint, traffic

I deployed a traffic manager on MS Azure. It has 2 endpoints one of them is enabled and online. bizarrely it turned to degraded, as I scaled down some Vms then scaled them back to their original size as I suspected they may be the cause.  I went through all MS.support (which is not accurate when it comes to troubleshoot traffic manager) and run invoke-webrequest  powesrhell cmd in vain. 
Here is my Traffic manager:
[image: LMS traffic manager]
[image: Inspect element on my Chrome Browser]

Here is part of my Json parameter file that created my endpoint:
[image]

How can I track my traffic manager and bring it back online.

As I wanted to redeploy the whole structure within Azure portal I got the following error:
Deployment template validation failed: '**Circular dependency detected on resource**: '*/subscriptions/xxxxx-xx-xx-xx/resourceGroups/PcloudOxa/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/PcloudOxa-mongo1'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)*

Comment: No sure what the screenshot shows. Does your endpoint (now in "Degraded") return `200 OK` if you `curl -i` to it from the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems somethings wrong with your app.
Error "502 bad gateway" is often caused by application level issues, such as:
1.requests taking a long time
2.application using high memory/CPU
3.application crashing due to an exception.

As you mentioned, you scaled down some Vms, maybe your app in a wrong status, so we should check your app first, make sure it running correctly.

Maybe we can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: the cmd. : Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://lms-pcloudoxa-tm.trafficmanager.net -UseBasicParsing. 
 gave nothign but a set of errors like : Invoke-WebRequest : Couldn't connect to server. ...etc.   Is there any step by step procedure to troubelshpoot a degraded traffic manager .

Comment: this deployment is related to Microsoft Open Edx .

Comment: @SAM.Am can you access your website without traffic manager, for example, you can access your website xxx.cloudapp.com?

Comment: I get a server error. I created 3 traffic manager. all of them were fine, but few days ago I resized them all to less resource consuming servers when one of them  has degraded one of its endpoints.

Comment: Do you mean you can't access your endpoint 3 directly (not via traffic manager)? if yes, we should check the endpoints status. by the way, if the endpoint 3 is ok, maybe we can try to remove and re-add it to traffic manager.

Comment: I deleted the degraded endpoint and recreated it in vain. My endpoint is an external one. ( I updated my Question above and added the endpoint Json parameters part that created it).   What could make the endpoint degraded?

Comment: @SAM.Am Can you browse your websitelms-pcloudxa-slot1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/   I can't browse it, please check it, maybe we should restart this web app.

Comment: try the following  CNAME  ddns record that points to to the original URl address .  Use  this Url :  
https://moocs.elearning.procloud.bh

The inspection element gives: Status Code:502 Bad Gateway

Comment: lms-pcloudxa-slot1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com  point to this URL?

Comment: here is the Nslookup  cmd :
C:\Users\medcsha>nslookup   moocs.elearning.procloud.bh
Server:  man-dc2.manama.moebh.net
Address:  10.18.2.22

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    lms-pcloudoxa-slot1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
Address:  52.168.18.51
Aliases:  moocs.elearning.procloud.bh
          lms-pcloudoxa-tm.trafficmanager.net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146126/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-sam-am).

Comment: I tried to redeploy the whole structure through the portal: and I got  this error:  'Circular dependency detected on resource"